# Как обрезать фон, выходящий за пределы контейнера?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не понимаю почему верхней строке я обрезала,а во второй он ведет себя не правильно,я так понимаю это опять гриды не дают обрезать или в чем дело?

```
.catalog-img7{
background-image: url("img/vorota.png");
background-size: no-repeat;
  /* background-position: center; */
/* background-size: cover; */
width: 28%;
height: 340px;
margin-top: -5px;
}
.catalog-img7 p{
    font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C2C2C; 
    margin-left: -250px;

    
}
.catalog-img7 .les{
    /* width: 100%; */
    
    
}
```

Comment: Прикрепите минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Стили с разметкой не помешало бы увидеть

Comment: Я добавила фото,так как код размещать тут я не понимаю как его добавлять на этом форуме,так же я не понимаю почему все элементы когда добавляешь другие элементы,начинают смещаться 1-3px?

Comment: @EvaSmirnova Без кода и не скажешь. Это каруселька? Попробуйте вместо grid задать flex. Вариантом много может быть, не пощупав и не скажешь.